# trouble implementing twitter bootstrap accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am having trouble implementing twitter bootstrap's accordion feature and wondered if someone could take a look and point out why it isn't working:

```
<div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-group" style="display:none" id="View" data-bind="foreach:Types">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <div class="text_x-large header"><span data-bind="text:Name()"></span> 
                        <span class="icon-plus-sign-alt accordion-toggle"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="accordion-body collapse in" data-bind="template: { name: 'list', foreach: $data.Users }"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the last div calls the following to be placed within the div with class collapse:

```
<script type="text/html" id="list">
    <div class="accordion-inner">
        <h3 id="letter" data-bind="text: Letter"></h3>
        <div class="smoke_hover" >
            <div class="list_item">
                <span class="h2"><small data-bind="text: Name"></small></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean?

Comment: @isherwood when i click on ` <span class="icon-plus-sign-alt accordion-toggle"></span>` the inner div is not closing or opening

Comment: I see nested .accordion-group elements and no .accordion-heading. Maybe you just need to follow the guide a little closer. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse

Comment: @isherwood i went ahead and made the two adjustments adding `accordion-heading` and taking out of the `<div class="accordion-body collapse in" data-bind="template: { name: 'list', foreach: $data.Users }"></div>` from the accordion-heading into just the accordion-group but still not working when i click the icon

Comment: You should probably isolate the Bootstrap from the Knockout and find out which has the issue. It's too much to debug with what you have posted. Maybe put the rendered HTML in a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I rearranged your setup to be more like the `collapse` example from the bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse) and it worked like a charm

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jgdmq/